# Where is this statue?

Tags: japan, china, where-on-earth, identify-this

Where is [this statue](https://www.storehouse.co/stories/b8lqe)? I couldn't locate it via Google or TinEye:

[image: little girl with books on seesaw outweighs fat man with Game Boy]

Also, is [the Arabic text in the article](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85%D8%A9%20%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A9%0A%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84%20%D8%B8%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%81%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%20..%20%D8%AD%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%83%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%82%D9%8A%D9%82%D9%8A%20%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B3%20%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%AD%D9%85%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%AC%D8%B3%D9%85%D9%83%D8%8C%20%D8%A8%D9%84%20%D8%A8%D8%AD%D8%AC%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%83%D8%B1%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%B9%D9%82%D9%84%D9%83) an accurate translation of those characters?

> Japanese wisdom - Zarif statue in Japan .. your size is not the true
>   weight of the fat in your body, but the size of the thought in your
>   mind

Comment: From that russian site found with google search by image: [https://fotostrana.ru/public/post/232614/969949603/](https://fotostrana.ru/public/post/232614/969949603/), the picture is in China: [english translation](https://goo.gl/GWULeN)

Comment: @mouviciel That is most certainly not the original image. The one given in the OP is dated 11 September 2015, while the lower-quality Russian repost is dated 4 March 2016.

Comment: The text on the center post of the statue is in Chinese, not Japanese. (Most characters are illegible at this resolution, but the use of 之 is a dead giveaway.)

Comment: Misread it due the angle and the typeface: it's actually 是.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This statue is in [Heihe (黑河), Heilongjiang, China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heihe), on a riverside promenade on the south side of the Amur River, opposite the Russian city of Blagoveshchensk to the north.  Here's a [random visitor's album](http://www.yododo.com/album/01400EABA0E302FAFF808081400E5E39) of other sights in the vicinity, and here are a few more views of the statue:

http://www.qyhbds.com/Product/xiaoyuandiaosu/3068.html
http://www.mychery.net/forum/bin/ut/topic_show.cgi?id=1675339&h=1&bpg=1&age=0

The inscription reads "知識就是力量" (知识就是力量 in Simplified Chinese), or "Knowledge is power", a reference to [Francis Bacon's famous phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientia_potentia_est) and much pithier than the Arabic article claims.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis I think you're reading a bit too much into this?  The OP asked if the text is "an accurate translation of those Japanese characters", and the answer to that question is that no, it's not.

Comment: true, I haven't read that part, i thought it is just about the location. Sorry.